# InfluxDB Continuous Query without GROUP BY time

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I want to count the number of events during last 1 week from a measurement X and store the count into another measurement Y periodically using an InfluxDB CONTINUOUS QUERY. However it seems **"GROUP BY time"** is mandatory in the query. This results in splitting of the result into multiple time range windows. Is there a way to disable GROUP BY or specify some duration in GROUP BY that doesn't result in splitting of the result?

**Continuous Query**

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_advanced_every_for" ON "transportation"
RESAMPLE EVERY 1h FOR 7d
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("event_name")) INTO "weekly_event_count" FROM "daily_event_count" GROUP BY time(7d)
END
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM weekly_event_count
```

**Output**

```
time                   count
----                   -----
2020-08-20T00:00:00Z   25000 -->I expected the timestamp to be 2020-08-19 as the query was run on 2020-08-26
```